# Quickest way to power rank?

Tags: trove

So, right now in trove, I'm power level 312, but I'm wondering, what **is** the quickest way to get to power rank 400? I've got a shadow weapon, and 2 resplendent gear, and a quietly, but that only brings me to 312, with me also being level 14 and mastery 15. I'm trying to get into the shadow tower, but that requires me to be power rank 400. What is a great way to power rank? Get more shadow weapons? Loot collect more?

I also can't get dragons, cause
1. I don't use money on trove
2. I'm trying to get the lunar dragon,

And I can't waste flux.
So, all I'm asking is, what is the fastest way to power rank?

Answer (score 2):

## Possibilities to increase your Power Rank

## Equipment

- Add/Increase stats with Pearls of Wisdom (Expensive, and only gives you ~10 PR per Pearl)
- Upgrade Weapons with Flux. Should be just done with Shadow equipment or above because you can't upgrade Resplendent items or below to the next rarity level. (Expensive)

**Conclusion**: Full maxed and pearled Stellar Items give you 1k Power Rank each (3k Power Rank total)

## Gems

Gems are the way to go if you want to increase your PR. But, like everywhere, you need flux (+ dust) to increase your gems. Here a short guideline to Gems and increase if Power Rank:

### Small Gems:

If your Power Rank is below 5k:

1. Farm in the highest Uber you can get.
2. Pick the Gems with the highest PR, ignore the stats.
3. Upgrade these Gems until you can go into the next Uber.
4. Once you can get into the next Uber, you get better gems.
5. Repeat.

Once you reach Power Rank 5000, you should start looking for the stats
because until Power Rank 10000 you need a long time. And you want good stats to farm as fast and efficient as possible. (And be useful in shadow towers)

### Big Gems:

Big Gems are very easy gettable, but time-gated. There are a few possbilities to get big gems:

**Contest**:

- Always make sure that you are with the contested class in the Top 25.000 because you are getting a **Empowered Gem Box** as reward. This could get problematic if you don't have the class. But if you have the class, it shouldn't be too hard. **(Once per week)**
- There is also always another contest like `Blocks placed`, `Blocks destroyed` etc. and it is always random. A good thing about this contest is, that you can compete even without end-game equipment. Even if equipment like the Tank-Turtle etc. are making the contest easier, you always have a good chance. **(Once per week)**
- Another way to get Empowered Gem Boxes is the Shadow Tower. If you kill the Daughter of the Moon in different difficulties you get lunar souls which you can exchange against Empowered Gem Boxes in the [Shadowy Market](http://trove.wikia.com/wiki/Shadowy_Market) at the end of every Shadow Tower. **(Once per week)**

> **Normal**: 1 Lunar Soul
>
> **Hard**: 2 Lunar Souls
>
> **Ultra**: 3 Lunar Souls

**Conclusion**: Gems are the main part of your PR. The more you progress, the bigger is the part they are giving you. If you have full maxed stellar gems, they can give you around ~2k PR on the big Gems, and ~1,5k on the small ones. (~15k in total)

[Note: Your class should be high enough to fill as much gem slots as possible. Gems you can't equip, don't give you PR.]

## Ring/Ally/Dragons etc.

The following are nice to have, but not nessecary and not very important to increase your PR because their amount is very low, or not worth the effort just for PR. (But the stats etc. are nice and important for your character.)

- **Rings**: You can get Rings to increase your PR. The maximum amount you can get from a Ring is ~400. I wouldn't recommend to get a Shadow 4 Ring JUST for PR because they are very expensive. (Flux <-> PR ratio is bad)
- **Allys**: Allys are also giving you PR. But it's not even worth mentioning because the maximum amount you get is 70. (Flux <-> PR ratio is incredible bad)
- **Dragons**: Dragon Buffs are giving you an okay amount of PR. I would recommend to get Dragons if you can, because the Magic find you get from finishing a dragon is very usefull, and the buffs in general too. (Flux <-> PR ratio is okay)
- **Mastery**: On some mastery levels you get a buff which increases your stats. I don't know how much it is because I already skipped these levels a long time ago. But it should be something around ~500 if you have all. (Not sure, don't rely on this information)

[Note: Always keep a good balance between PR, and your power/strengh in general. If you are too weak to farm in higher ubers, focus on improving stats and gear.]

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately there isn't any easy to raise your power rank without using flux. The only ways that come to mind without using flux is mastery level and leveling your classes. With the new mantle of power update, the fastest way to increase your power rank is with gems. 9 fully leveled gems can add over 3000 to your power rank. Other than gems, getting better gear is the next best way.

Answer (score 0):

Nice guide for them to know what it takes on the road to 16k.

I may be quite late to the party on this topic, but honestly, if you're not quite to the level of power rating to do Shadow Tower at all... then you should do the following.

1 -- Concern yourself with raising your class levels first.  Each fully leveled class is worth a few mastery levels.

2 -- If you can do uber maps, FIND RECIPE DUNGEONS FIRST.  They're short, easy to navigate, and yield 2 mastery points per recipe.  Plus, if you have all the recipes for a biome collected, you can turn the extra scrolls into blank scrolls for Runecrafting later on.

3 -- Level the professions.  It's expensive and takes some effort, but it's at least worth the mastery they give, and Runecrafting gives you more recipes and styles to raise mastery with, as well as access to tomes, which give you items when fully charged.  (Note: tomes are charged with experience, so you have to do dungeons to use them)

4 -- While in ubers, gem boxes may drop.  These boxes will yield gems and dust of varying elements when in normal ubers, and one type of element in elemental worlds (from uber 3 and onwards you'll see water, uber 5 has a skyland, and uber 7 a fireland) but gem boxes will always drop in the elemenal worlds.

5 -- Have you ever used the Marketplace?  You probably should look into it!  Stuff might be expensive, but I see the expense as a motivation to keep leveling and farming those materials.
You can also sell (most? some?) of what you don't want or need for the following materials that also function as currencies:  Flux, Eyes of Q'bthulu, tradable Chaos Chests (non-tradable ones coming soon in a future update), Penta-Forged Shadow Souls, Dragon Coins (partially farmable with biome challenges and legendary tome, tome CAN be bought with Cubits), and Glim.

6 -- Get those dragons!  They're worth both mastery and stat bonuses!  Certain ones can also glide and shoot bomb-like blasts, good for shortcutting dungeons.  Some need flux and dragon coins, as well as some other items, others need dragon coins, golden souls, and an item relevant to a biome (these take up to 100, basically 400 coins and 100 golden souls, but they're all worth the time.)

Worry more about Shadow Tower when you've got most of your collection squared away, that way you've got some bonuses behind you!  Never a bad idea to run it with your friends when you can run it, but honestly?  Get that mastery up first, and that means collect, collect, COLLECT!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend getting pearls, rank up weapons and get dragons. Have friends of some sort or random people trade you materials to get dragons for stat bonuses. Friends make Trove a breeze and can help big time. If your weak, let a stronger friend take out dungeons. You'll get the same loot (except weapons and armour)  and can sell it to the loot collecter in a cornerstone. Pearls can also be on random pieces of loot such as weapons.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest mastery rings for now until you can get to 400 because while u can't get good rank it is a good short term if your like 312